# finding by object key in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following object

```
{ join: {} }
```

I'd like to find it's default object from the array below

```
[
    { login: { label: 'Login', url: '#login' } },
    { join: { label: 'Join', url: '#join', theme: 'a' } },
    { home: { label: 'none', icon: 'home', url: '#', theme: 'a' } }
]
```

I'd like to loop through the array and match the key, in this case `'join'`.

This is what I have so far:

```
 var butt_to_find = { join: {} }
 var all_buttons = 'array above'
 var matching = _.find(all_buttons, function(default_button){
 return if default_butt key @ 1 is the same as butt_to_find key @ 1;
  });
```

This is the first time I've used underscore after hearing so much about it.
Any help, more than welcome

Comment: One minor (off-topic) point: You're using `label: 'none'`. Surely `label: null` (or omitting the `label` property) would more be a more accurate way to represent this? As written, I'd expect the word "none" to actually be rendered in the UI.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var buttons = [
  { login: { label: 'Login', url: '#login' } },
  { join: { label: 'Join', url: '#join', theme: 'a' } },
  { home: { label: 'none', icon: 'home', url: '#', theme: 'a' } }
]

_.find(buttons, function (button) { return 'join' in button })
```

The problem is that you're using a suboptimal data structure. This would make more sense, and produce simpler code:

```
var buttons = {
  login: {label: 'Login', url: '#login'},
  join: {label: 'Join', url: '#join', theme: 'a'},
  home: {label: 'none', icon: 'home', url: '#', theme: 'a'}
}

buttons.join // equivalent to the `_.find` line in the first example (but much simpler)
```

Perhaps you're using an array because the order of the buttons is important. In this case, I'd use an array of arrays:

```
var buttons = [
  ['login', {label: 'Login', url: '#login'}],
  ['join', {label: 'Join', url: '#join', theme: 'a'}],
  ['home', {label: 'none', icon: 'home', url: '#', theme: 'a'}]
]

_.find(buttons, function (button) { return button[0] === 'join' })
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - got me thinking about the data structure which really helped.

Comment: FWIW (and a little off topic) but I wouldn't use an array of arrays to retain order.  Use an array of keys for order and keept the buttons object as-is.  var buttons = {...};  var buttonsOrder = [ 'login','join','home'];  That way you only have to iterate arrays when you need order, and can do immediate lookups when you need the item.

Answer (score 4):

```
var matching =
( _.find
  ( all_buttons,
    function (button)
    { return _.keys(butt_to_find)[0] in button;
    }
  )
);
```

where `_.keys(butt_to_find)` evaluates to `['join']` (an array containing the keys of `butt_to_find`), `_.keys(butt_to_find)[0]` evaluates to `'join'` (the first element of said array), and `_.keys(butt_to_find)[0] in button` evaluates to either `true` or `false`, depending whether `button` contains `'join'` as a key. ([The `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is a regular JavaScript operator, not something added by underscore.js.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var def = {join: {}}
var defs = [
    { login: { label: 'Login', url: '#login' } },
    { join: { label: 'Join', url: '#join', theme: 'a' } },
    { home: { label: 'none', icon: 'home', url: '#', theme: 'a' } }
]
_.find(defs,function(item,key){
    return _.has(item,_.keys(def)[0])
})
```

You can also switch to the lodash library (a drop in version of underscore) and do this

```
_.compact(_.pluck(defs,_.keys(def)[0]))
```